# Performing difference in extracting coefficients from a sum

Tags: performance-tuning, replacement, polynomials

I have an expression

```
exp=1/(2 (2 + k)^2) (48 + 3 c + 12 a[2] + 2 c a[2] + c k a[2] + 40 a[3] + 
    20 k a[3] - 48 k dd[5] + 4 k^3 dd[5] + 64 dd[6] + 80 k dd[6] + 
    32 k^2 dd[6] + 4 k^3 dd[6]) Op[{J3[-2], J3[-2]}][
   Ket[vac]] + ((24 a[1] + 12 k a[1]) Op[{J3[-1], J3[-1]}][
   Ket[vac]])/(2 (2 + k)^2)
```

I'd like to extract the coefficient of the `Op[{...}][Ket[vac]]`, using `//. {\[Lambda]_ Op[l_][Ket[vac]] + x_ :> {\[Lambda], x}} /. {\[Lambda]_ Op[l_][Ket[vac]] :> {\[Lambda]}}`. It works as expected.

I can also replace the `a[i]`'s with `aa[i]`'s: `exp /. {a -> aa}`, and do the same thing, and it also output the same result.

However, the **performance** of the same computation on `exp` and `exp /. {a -> aa}` differ by quite a bit.

```
((exp) //. {\[Lambda]_ Op[l_][Ket[vac]] + x_ :> {\[Lambda], 
       x}} /. {\[Lambda]_ Op[l_][Ket[vac]] :> {\[Lambda]}} // Timing);
(exp /. {a -> aa} //. {\[Lambda]_ Op[l_][Ket[vac]] + 
       x_ :> {\[Lambda], x}} /. {\[Lambda]_ Op[l_][
       Ket[vac]] :> {\[Lambda]}} // Timing);
%/%% /. {a -> aa} // Simplify
```

which gives, for example,

```
{34., {1, {1}}}
```

**I wonder what causes the performance difference?**

(note that the performance on `exp/.{a->aaa}` and `exp` are roughly the same, so it seems `aa` is slightly special)